# How to merge two arrays when nothing works?

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-merge

I'm trying to merge two arrays, I've done it many times in other ways but now it doesn't work and I have no idea why, I'm sure that if you have a look we can get the solution!!

PHP FYLE

```
<?php
  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
  include("conex.phtml");

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  );
  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

  global $output;$output = array();      
  global $result;$result = array();      
  global $ret_obj_place;$ret_obj_place = array();      
  global $ret_obj_page2;$ret_obj_page2 = array();      
  global $pic_square;$link=Conectarse();

    if($user_id) {
    $user_id=$_GET['user_id'];
    $page_id=$_GET['page_id'];
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE page_id=" . $page_id, $link);
    if ($result){} else {
try {
        $fqlPlace = 'SELECT page_id,name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext FROM place WHERE page_id=' . $page_id;
        $ret_obj_place = $facebook->api(array(
                                   'method' => 'fql.query',
                                   'query' => $fqlPlace,
                                 ));   

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////        

        $fqlPage = 'SELECT pic_square, pic_big, fan_count, type FROM page WHERE page_id=' . $page_id;
        $ret_obj_page2 = $facebook->api(array(
                                   'method' => 'fql.query',
                                   'query' => $fqlPage,
                                 ));
     **//$output = array_merge($ret_obj_place, $ret_obj_page2);           

        $union = array_merge($ret_obj_place, $ret_obj_page2);
        $union = array_map('serialize', $union);

        global $data = array();

        foreach (array_unique($union) as $v) {
            $data[] = unserialize($v);**
        }
        //$union = array_merge($ret_obj_place, $ret_obj_page2);
        //$output = array_values(array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $union))));            

        displayResult($result, $output, $data);     
             ///////////////////////////////////////// 
       } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }}} else {

      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
      }

function displayResult($results, $output, $data){

    echo '' . json_encode($data) . ''; 
}

mysql_close($link);
exit(); 
?>
```

the direct output of each array is something like this

ARRAY 1

```
[{"page_id":"111812165504902","name":"Sevilla","description":"Seville is a Spanish city, Spain.","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["-5.98694","37.3772"]},"latitude":"37.3772","longitude":"-5.98694","checkin_count":"2083255","display_subtext":"City"}]
```

ARRAY 2

```
[{"pic_square":"https:\/\/fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net\/safe_image.php?d=AQALHDy62kBNTCO=q","pic_big":"https:\/\/fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net\/safe_image.php?d=AQA9I5AOB1ekj1OB&w=d","fan_count":"83323","type":"CITY"}]
```

When I check individualy the results of sending the array to the javascript, everything seems to be ok, but when I try to combine them, the data contained in the second array is "undefined". Have any idea

Comment: I don't know anything about using the facebook API but.. the arrays you are showing are in a JSON format, if they are not already being converted into arrays you need to run `json_decode($results, true);` <-- noticed the `true` this will return an array not an object. You should have no problems merging then.

Comment: i think array 1 and array 2 is not in array format. may be its look like in json format .. convert them to array then apply array_merge

Answer (score 0):

//Change The Line

```
$union = array_merge(json_decode($ret_obj_place), json_decode($ret_obj_page2));
```